# Boot Screen gone away. 13.04

Tags: boot, 13.04, screen

i dont know what i did or if it was after an upgrade but my Ubuntu boot screen is gone. It's been replaced by a flashing curser in the upper lefthand side of the screen followed by a prompt for my password that goes away then it boots into the os. Any idea how this can be fixed? Also now when i shut down or restart i get a quick flash of messages. something about swap. Cant make it out. it goes by to quick. dont know if its related. Anyway, any help would be great.

Comment: Paste the output of `cat /etc/default/grub`. In case it boots into command line interface, `sudo start lightdm` and you'll get the login display manager.

Comment: Do you use NVidia driver?

Answer (score 0):

Open the GRUB config file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

---

Next, change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="......."
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

---

Finally, run update-grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't directly edit grub boot menu as you can make typo mistakes. Use a tool like grub-customizer or a tool like unetbooting. It your awindows user you can also run EasybootBCD but use it with caution.

> sudo apt-get grub-customizer

if you want to change your GUI interface or update your graphics adapter run

> > sudo dpkg_reconfigure

it will ask you what GUI is your preference , KDM,lXDM, or mdm

if you still cant get it to start boot from the liveCD or bootRecovery CD and select "rescue"